# Integer solutions of $m^2+(m+1)^2=n^4+(n+1)^4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

$m^2+(m+1)^2=n^4+(n+1)^4$

Integral (integer) solutions needed
I could find only four, are there others

-1 & 0 give both sides as 1.

Answer (score 7):

$$n^4+(n+1)^4=2n^4+4n^3+6n^2+4n+1$$ $$=2(n^4+2n^3+3n^2+2n+1)-1=2y^2-1$$ where $y=n^2+n+1$, so you want $2y^2-1$ to be a sum of consecutive squares. It's not going to happen (except for the instances you have already found): $(y-1)^2+y^2$ is too small, and $y^2+(y+1)^2$ is too big.

Answer (score 2):

Solving 
$$m^2+(m+1)^2=n^4+(n+1)^4$$
for $m$ gives you
$$m=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{4n^4+8n^3+12n^2+8n+1}}{2}$$
However, for $n\not=0,-1$, since
$$2n^2+2n+1\lt \sqrt{4n^4+8n^3+12n^2+8n+1}\lt 2n^2+2n+2,$$
we know that $\sqrt{4n^4+8n^3+12n^2+8n+1}$ cannot be an integer.

Hence, we have $n=0,-1$.