# Show that, there are no integers $(m, n)$ such that, $m^2 + (m + 1)^2 = n^4 + (n + 1)^4$ .

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that, there are no integers $(m, n)$ such that, $m^2 + (m + 1)^2 = n^4 + (n + 1)^4$ .

I really don't know how to approach this one i tried factorizing but it didn't seem to help , any hint would be appreciated .

Comment: Someone please edit this for exponents !

Comment: $(m,n)=(0,0)$ is a solution.

Comment: So are $(m,n) = (-1,0), (0,-1)$.

Comment: And $(-1,-1)$ $\quad$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307773/integer-solutions-of-m2m12-n4n14.

Comment: ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Comment: Thanks everyone (Btw how is that blank comment ? )